# What type of data should I use (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, types

Data type for the string - VARCHAR. data type for numbers - INT. What data type will be used for the string with numbers? E.g., "test123".

Comment: Normally you would use `VARCHAR`, unless they are really long. How long are those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is a string, even if some of its characters are digits. You can use a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

Varchar. A string with numbers in it is still a string.